# Convert RealmResults to RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I have one  realmObject custom class

```
public class TerminalTable extends RealmObject implements Serializable{

public String logo = "";

public String company_id = "";

public String company = "";

public String company_identification = "";

public String address = "";

public String serial_number = "";

public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public String getCompany_id() {
    return company_id;
}


public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}


public String getCompany_identification() {
    return company_identification;
}



public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}


public String getSerial_number() {
    return serial_number;
}


public String getTerminal_id() {
    return terminal_id;
}




public String getAdditional_text() {
    return additional_text;
}



public String terminal_id = "";


public String additional_text = "";
```

}

I successfully inserted some elements in my database,now I want to select it.I wrote some code and this code working correctly ,Here is a source

```
  public static  RealmResults getTerminalTable()
{
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(realm -> {
        terminalTable = realm.where(TerminalTable.class).findAll();
    });
    return terminalTable;
}
```

As you can see my function returns RealmResults object,How I can rewrite my function to can return TerminalTable object, not  RealmResults 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why are you executing transaction for read purpose.

`findAll()` returns collection object, then you have to iterate objects.

for specific record there is alternative `findFirst()`.

What you are looking for, can be done by following way.

1. below will fetch all the records.

   ```
   public static List<TerminalTable> getTerminalTable()
   {
   List<TerminalTable> terminalTable;
   try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {

       terminalTable = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(TerminalTable.class).findAll()); // return all data as list
   }
   return terminalTable;
   }
   ```
2. to fetch single record from realm

   ```
   public static TerminalTable getSingleTerminalTable()
   {
   TerminalTable terminalTable;
   try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
       terminalTable = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(TerminalTable.class).findFirst());
   }
   return terminalTable;
   }
   ```

If you want to deal with managed objects then query should look like

```
terminalTable = realm.where(TerminalTable.class).findFirst();
```